# The application account information was incorrect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

[image]

While Validating the app getting this error.
After Restarting the Xcode and Mac Machine.

Comment: Same here. Validation went through correctly and the same error appeared on submission

Comment: Same here on Yosemite and Application Loader 3.0

Comment: This is also confirmed on OS 10.9.4

Comment: Also happening on OS 10.9.4 with Application Loader 3.0. (Just spent an hour on this - creating a new dev iTunes account doesn't help either fwiw.)

Comment: Downloaded xCode 6.1 on OS 10.9.5 - same error

Comment: Got same error with Maverick Xcode 6.0,

On validating App its display
"Discription not available"

And on Uploading App display
"The application account information was incorrect"

Comment: People - STOP posting "me too" answers. If you have more to add, post a comment, NOT an answer.

Comment: Problem appears to be resolved. Test via iTunes Producer 3.1 on OS 10.9.5.

Comment: The Problem is not yet Fixed because i was using 10.9.2 OS and Xcode 5.1.1 , Will it work on these versions.

Answer (score 6):

Apple fixed whatever caused the issue. Problem appears to be resolved.

Successful Package delivery via iTunes Producer 3.1 on OS 10.9.5.

Comment: Fixed for OS X Yosemite 10.10 and Application Loader 3.0