# Getting strange error on iTunes Connect - ITC.halliday.error.unavailble with Xcode 6 iOS 8.1SDK

Tags: xcode6, ios8.1

I'm trying to upload a new build via Xcode 6 to iTunes Connect release, and see a few errors, which might be related.

The build validates successfully, but when I try to submit I get this error:

[image]

When I check out the Prelease section on iTunes Connect, i see this strange error "ITC.halliday.error.unavailble"

[image]

Are these related? Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

Apple seems to have fixed something on their end. I was just able to submit successfully. The "ITC.halliday.error.unavailble" message disappeared.

Comment: Me too :(. Since you posted this 10 minutes ago, let's assume it's a temporary issue that will go away.

Comment: Although we *did* submit about 2 hours ago without problem.

Comment: yeah I've been tracking another thread with people having similar issues -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512539/the-application-account-information-was-incorrect

Comment: Oh & I emailed apple support and will update this thread when they get back to me

Comment: New error! ITC.prerelease.pagemsg.startTesting.enableTFandInviteTester